# I'm having difficulties with my sequelize associations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

> Before asking this question I have spent days finding a solution that
> solved my problem but no luck. Every question that I search on Google
> is not valid. I have searched so much that every link in the result is
> pink.

Hey everyone. I'm struggling to create associations between 3 models: Comment, User and Post. I'm making a simple web blog with authentication posts and comments under the posts. Explanation will be more than appreciated.

Here are my models so far.

```js
// comment.js
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Comment extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models.Post);
    }
  }
  Comment.init(
    {
      comment: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      postId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      authorId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Comment",
    }
  );
  return Comment;
};
```

```js
// post.js
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Post extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.hasMany(models.Comment);
    }
  }
  Post.init(
    {
      title: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      description: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false },
      imageUrl: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Post",
    }
  );
  return Post;
};
```

```js
// user.js
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

And I'm getting this error in my post controller when I'm trying to get all the comments that have respective post Id

```
TypeError: include.model.getTableName is not a function
    at Function._validateIncludedElement (C:\Users\micha\Desktop\blog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:579:30)
    at C:\Users\micha\Desktop\blog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:509:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function._validateIncludedElements (C:\Users\micha\Desktop\blog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:504:39)
    at Function.findAll (C:\Users\micha\Desktop\blog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1723:12)
    at async Function.findOne (C:\Users\micha\Desktop\blog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1917:12)
    at async exports.getPostById (C:\Users\micha\Desktop\blog\src\controllers\post.contoller.js:14:18)
```

Here's the controller snippet where the error occurs

```js
    const post = await Post(sequelize, DataTypes).findOne({
      where: {
        id: req.params.postId,
      },
      include: [{ model: Comment, as: "comments" }],
    });
```

Thanks in advance and also thanks for providing your time. I hope we'll be able to go through this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to switch your query. Instead of findOne on `Post`, you can findAll on `Comment`. Like this

```js
Comment.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Post,
    where: { id: req.params.postId }
  }]
})
```